# Looping through a groupby and adding a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to write a small script to get through some data (around 50k rows/file) and my original file looks like this:

```
    Label   ID  TRACK_ID    QUALITY POSITION_X  POSITION_Y  POSITION_Z  POSITION_T  FRAME   RADIUS  VISIBILITY  MANUAL_COLOR    MEAN_INTENSITY  MEDIAN_INTENSITY    MIN_INTENSITY   MAX_INTENSITY   TOTAL_INTENSITY STANDARD_DEVIATION  ESTIMATED_DIAMETER  CONTRAST    SNR
    ID1119  1119    9       6.672     384.195     122.923   0   0   0   5   1   -10921639   81.495  0   0   255 7905    119.529 5.201   1   0.682
    ID2237  2237    9       7.078     381.019     122.019   0   1   1   5   1   -10921639   89.381  0   0   255 8670    122.301 5.357   1   0.731
    ID2512  2512    9       7.193     377.739     120.125   0   2   2   5   1   -10921639   92.01   0   0   255 8925    123.097 5.356   1   0.747
    (...)
    ID1102  1102    18      4.991     808.857     59.966    0   0   0   5   1   -10921639   52.577  0   0   255 5100    103.7   4.798   1   0.507
    (...)
```

Its a rather big table with up to 50k rows. Now not all the data is important to me, I mainly need the Track_ID and the X and Y Position. 
So I create a dataframe using the excel file and only access the corresponding columns

```
IN   df = pd.read_excel('.../sample.xlsx', 'Sheet1',parse_cols="D, F,G")
```

And this works as expected. Each track_id is basically one set of data that needs to be analyzed. So the straight forward way is to group the dataframe by track_id

```
IN Grouping = df.groupby("TRACK_ID")
```

Also works as intended. Now I need to grab the first POSITION_X value of each group and substract them from the other POSITION_X values in that group.
Now, I already read that looping is probably not the best way to go about it, but I have no idea how else to do it.

```
for name, group in Grouping:
    first_X = group.iloc[0, 1]
    vect = group.iloc[1:,1] - first_X
```

This stores the value in vect, which, if I print it out, gives me the correct value. However, I have the problem that I do not know how to add it now to a new column.
Maybe someone could guide me into the correct direction. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
This was suggested by chappers

```
def f(grouped):
    grouped.iloc[1:] = 0
    return grouped

grouped = df.groupby('TRACK_ID')
df['Calc'] = grouped['POSITION_X'].apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0]) grouped['POSITION_X'].apply(f)
for name, group in grouped:
    print name
    print group

Input:    
     TRACK_ID  POSITION_X  POSITION_Y
0          9     384.195     122.923
1          9     381.019     122.019
2          9     377.739     120.125
3          9     375.211     117.224
4          9     373.213     113.938
5          9     371.625     110.161
6          9     369.803     106.424
7          9     367.717     103.239
8         18     808.857      59.966
9         18     807.715      61.032
10        18     808.165      63.133
11        18     810.147      64.853
12        18     812.084      65.084
13        18     812.880      63.683
14        18     812.083      62.203
15        18     810.041      61.188
16        18     808.568      62.260

Output for group == 9
   TRACK_ID  POSITION_X  POSITION_Y     Calc
0         9     384.195     122.923  384.195
1         9     381.019     122.019   -3.176
2         9     377.739     120.125   -6.456
3         9     375.211     117.224   -8.984
4         9     373.213     113.938  -10.982
5         9     371.625     110.161  -12.570
6         9     369.803     106.424  -14.392
7         9     367.717     103.239  -16.478
```

So expected Output would be that the very first calc value of every group is 0

Comment: not sure of another method other then a loop but to keep track of the values just append them to a new list. 

`new_list = []
loop start:
    do some stuff
    new_list.append(vect)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of approaching it, using the apply method to subtract the first item from all the other obs.

```
df = DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo',
                           'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
                    'C' : [1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1]})

grouped = df.groupby('A')
df['C1'] = grouped['C'].apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0])
```

This would have input:

```
     A  C
0  foo  1
1  foo  2
2  foo  3
3  foo  4
4  bar  4
5  bar  3
6  bar  2
7  bar  1
```

and output

```
     A  C  C1
0  foo  1   0
1  foo  2   1
2  foo  3   2
3  foo  4   3
4  bar  4   0
5  bar  3  -1
6  bar  2  -2
7  bar  1  -3
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, in principle it works very well and I really like your short way. I never really worked with lambda operators, therefor I am just reading up on them now. One problem is, preferably the Value for the 0s would return 0 and not the initial X value. any idea?

Comment: Could you provide an expected input/output? I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: I don't follow, could you post a minimal data set that I can reproduce showing your expected input and output?

Comment: Oh right in that case you don't need the adjustment thingy I've made; I'll edit my answer.